# Call JavaScript Function in ASP:TEXTBOX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have just tried to add value in Two Text boxes and want to display in third text box.and I also tried to call my JavaScript Function in ASP:TextBox.but the function is not properly. I have Attached my code below to it.

I want to know how to call JavaScript Function in ONCLICK Event on  ASP:TEXTBOX

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" onchange="javascript:addition(this)">        </asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</form>
<script>
    var text1 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>');
    var text2 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>');
    var text3 = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>');
         var t1 = text1.value;
         var t2 = text2.value;
         var t3;
    function addition(){
t3 = parseInt(tl).value + parseInt(t2).value;
        document.getElementById('TextBox3').value = t3;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Can call JS function in `onblur` event.

Comment: Already tried with onblur but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes you are right, see my answer.

Comment: So the `blur` was your answer ?!! as you accepted ! as you experienced the `blur` is not fire when you focusing `TextBox3`, it is not the thing as you requested,, anyway `focus` in JQuery or `onfocusin` in JavaScript is your solution not `blur` !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" onblur ="javascript:addition(this)">  </asp:TextBox>
```

if you are using JQuery it is better to use `focus` event such as:

```
$('<%=TextBox3.ClientID%>').focus(function() {
  //Additional code here
});
```

but yes `onblur` may doesn't work as you want because the blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus as I mentioned, So it is better to use `focus` event.

Another way is Handeling `onfocusin` like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" onfocusin="javascript:addition(this)">  </asp:TextBox>
```

the `onblur` behaves like `onfocusout`.

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#TextBox3").blur(function () {
//     Do Somthing
});
```